# Math Based Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm new to this but I was hoping I could get some help.

So the problem I was given is as follows:

Given a list of distinct positive integers, write a function that returns a list of two positive integers a and b representing. The ratio of a/b should be double that of the radius of the last integer. This example should shed so more light:

Given [4,30,50] we know the distance from 4 to 30 is 26 and the distance from 30 to 50 is 20. So now there must be some radius given these locations that the first radius is double that of the last. A solution to this is the first radius is 12, second is 14, and last is 6. As you can see the last one is half of the first. As well as 12 +14 = 26 and 14+6 =20. So all the cogs will move each other. Given there is no solution return [-1,-1], something like [4,17,50] would have no solution.

Here's the code I am trying to use for checking, but it definitely does not perform.

```
public static int[] answer(int[] pegs)
{
  int[] noSolution = [-1,-1];
  int[] results = new int[2];
  int secondGear = pegs[1];
  int firstGear = pegs[0];
  int maxRadius = secondGear - firstGear;

  int checkRadius = 0;
  while(checkRadius < maxRadius)
  {
      int distance = maxRadius;
      int changingRadius = distance - checkRadius; //Using this to get varying radii to see which one works
      for(int i =1; i<pegs.length-1;i++)
      {
          distance = pegs[i+1] - pegs[i];
          if(changingRadius >= distance)
          { 
              break;
          }
          else
          {
             changingRadius = distance - changingRadius // Given that our radius is less than the distance 
                                                        // let's continue to check if it is the same for the other distances 
          }
       }
       if((changingRadius*2) == checkRadius)
       { 
           break; // Should be the case we found the right radius
       }
       checkRadius++; // Didnt find the right one, increment and test a new radius
```

Any help is much apperciated because this has me pretty stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set this up as a system of linear equations.

```
     --          ----
  /      \    /        \
 (        )  (          )  (  )
(----><----)(-----><-----)(-><-)
 (    4   )x1(    30    )x2(50)
  \      /    \        /
     --          ----
```

Let `x1` and `x2` be the mesh points of the first two gears and the last two gears respectively. We have the equation

```
x1 + x2
------- = 30,
   2
```

since the middle gear is midway between the mesh points. The equation for the first gear being twice as large as the last is

```
x1 - 4 = 2*(50 - x2).
```

In general, we get a linear system like

```
[1/2 1/2  0   0  ...  0   0 ] [ x1 ]   [ c1 ]
[ 0  1/2 1/2  0  ...  0   0 ] [ x2 ]   [ c2 ]
 ...........................   ....  =  ....
[ 0   0   0   0  ... 1/2 1/2] [xn-2]   [cn-1]
[ 1   0   0   0  ...  0   2 ] [xn-1]   [c1 + 2*cn-1],
```

which can be solved in linear time by standard methods. Then check that the unique candidate thus obtained implies positive (and integral?) radii.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you're doing in the math. However, if I were to give something like [4,30,35,50]. Then I seem to get the wrong answer using the same approach. If you wouldn't mind would explain how we can us this approach with the set I just gave. I believe the answer should be 12.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured what you were saying. I just have to implement into my code now. Thank you very much